# Onboarding walkthrough or let them explore?

Tags: web-app, selection, dashboard, onboarding

Working on improving the onboarding process of an app. It's a large app with multiple modules (think Atlassian), and I can't decide whether or not to **start users off on the main dashboard** to let them choose a module from the left menu, or to have them **choose before they enter the platform**. Thoughts? Any data support one way or the other?

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation here is to do some research and learn from your first-time users.
Learn what they are struggling with in the first steps after signing up for the platform.  Do they need to populate that dashboard? How are they going to do that? Is that clear for them? :)